# Skip testsuite if fixture fails in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am having a testsuite which is a class and each testmethod is a testcase. I am also having a fixture for each method (testcase) which does some basic things. I am having a strange requirement where I want to skip all the testcases in the test suite if testfixture fails.

below is the sample suite I am having

```
class TestFeature:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def _wrapper(self):
        print("Some precomditions")
        yield
        print("some post conditions")

    def test_first_testcase(self):
        print("First testcas")

    def test_second_testcase(self):
        print("second testcas")

    def test_third_testcase(self):
        print("Third testcas")
```

Now I want if my fixture fails, I want to abort this test suite. Suppose My first testcase failed. Fixture for next test case failed. I want to abort the suite and do not want to execute third testcase.

How to do this in pytest

Answer (score 1):

pytest [allows you](http://pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures) to do it by using the `x` flag:

```
pytest -x
```

You can also use `maxfail` flag if you wish to customize the number of failures before quitting:

```
--maxfail=NUMBER
```

In case you need to exit the test suite from within your code, you can use the [`exit`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-exit) method:

```
import pytest

pytest.exit()
```

Comment: I think this will also account for testcase failure. I want to abort only if fixture fails

Comment: Have you though about calling `pytest.exit` from within the fixture?

Comment: Is there a gracefull way of doing that. Pytest.exit will exit abrutly. I want something like it should skip and print message like testcase skipped as we use xfail or skip

Comment: `pytest.skip(msg)`